# Doubts about pages and custom controllers for components

Tags: dxa, dxa-net

Until now I've just only recovered components from Tridion in my DXA using ContentProvider.GetEntityModel. The thing is that now I need to create pages and add components to them. I have created a test page (test.html) with only one component with some text fields.

I have created this controller in my DXA:

[image]

In the Global.asax:

[image]

I've created a view for my page (MainPage) that only contains this:

[image]

I have also a View for the Region Main containing:

[image]

I also have a model for my component (with all the semantics necessary):

[image]

And a controller (it doesn't do much for the moment), which is the one specified in the component template:

[image]

And a view Story (which is the one specified in the component template) containing a simple text.

I have registered all:

[image]

I thought that doing this the application would load the main view and then it would enter in each controller associated to the components included (in this case only one), but it keeps failing here:

[image]

I don't know if I'm not understanding how this works or if I've configured someting wrongly, could anybody help me here?

Thanks a lot

Mer

Comment: Can you check and provide what error you are getting in site log file.

Comment: @SayantanBasu It's the same I saw in Visual Studio: 2018-10-09 12:44:04,388 [6] ERROR - Execution of the child request failed. Please examine the InnerException for more information.
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Execution of the child request failed. Please examine the InnerException for more information. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/test.html' was not 
found or does not implement IController.was not 
found or does not implement IController.

Comment: How does your AreaRegistration look? What is the namespace of this AreaRegistration and what is the namespace of your StoryController? Which DXA version are you using?

Comment: Hint: see the comment in [BaseAreaRegistration.RegisterArea](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/2.0/Sdl.Web.Mvc/Configuration/BaseAreaRegistration.cs)

Comment: @RickPannekoek this is my AreaRegistration https://imgur.com/a/UJ7paGA

Comment: Ok, so your AreaRegistration is in namespace `Sdl.Web.Site`. Where is your Controller?

Comment: @RickPannekoek ok, I see it now, my controller is in another namespace. I'll correct it and retry. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It also required to configure meta data of component templates and page template to use custom controllers. Also with the change of controller names you require to change the path of corresponding views. We can relate this with OTBut of the box DXA demo site, Component View's folder name is Entity as component templates are configured to work with EntityController. Similarly for Page Views folder name is Page as it is using PageController.

You should go through [documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v10/GUID-01A0F1FA-C15E-4549-A2A8-50DD8FA42F80) to implement custom area and place custom controllers and views there.

Comment: Hi Mukesh, I've already configured the metadata of both templates indicating the controller and the view in each case. What do you mean with "Also with the change of controller names you require to change the path of corresponding views"? I have 3 folders in the Views Folder inside my area: Entity (containing the view of Story), PageX (that's the name of the controller configured in the page template, containing the MainPage view) and Region (containing the Main view). Thank you for your help

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your queries. Please check if this can help you further identify your issue. You can relate DXA application with any standard MVC application for Views, controllers and routing.